# equation of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, cross-product

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$Given three linearly independent vectors, $\dot c(t)$, $v(t)$, $\dot v(t)$, and $F(t,s) = c(t) + sv(t)$, we want to calculate 
$$
\Brak{\frac{\partial^2 F(t,s)}{\partial t\, \partial s},N},
$$
where $N$ is normal vector on $F$.

That is
$$
\Brak{\frac{\partial^2 F(t,s)}{\partial t\, \partial s},N}
  = \frac{ \Brak{\dot v(t), (\dot c(t) + s \dot v(t)) \times v(t)}}{\|(\dot c(t) + s \dot v(t)) \times v(t)\|}
  = \frac{\Brak{\dot v(t),(\dot c(t))\times v(t)}}{\|(\dot c(t)+s \dot v(t))\times v(t)\|}.
$$

My question is, why is the last equality right? That is, why can I  write $(\dot c(t) + s\dot v(t)) \times v(t) = \dot c(t) \times v(t)$ when $\dot c(t)$, $v(t)$ and $\dot v(t)$ are linearly independent?

Comment: I think your statement is wrong. Try $c(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, 0)$, and $c(t)=v(t)$, the equality holds only for $s=0$.

Comment: It's from our professor's script. Maybe I should edit, that they are connected by the function $F(t,s)=c(t)+sv(t)$.

Comment: I recomend you rewrite your question with more details

Comment: I've rewrited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$It's not that $(\dot{c}(t) + s\dot{v}(t)) \times v(t) = \dot{c}(t) \times v(t)$, but that
$$
\Brak{\dot{v}(t), s\dot{v}(t) \times v(t)} = 0
$$
because the cross product is orthogonal to each of its "factors". Consequently,
$$
\Brak{\dot{v}(t), (\dot{c}(t) + s\dot{v}(t)) \times v(t)}
= \Brak{\dot{v}(t), \dot{c}(t) \times v(t)}.
$$
This is true whether or not the vectors in question are linearly independent.